# How to avoid, that the height of the sticky element influences the content?

Tags: html, css

I need a sticky element at the bottom, that moves up and shows the footer if the user scrolled to the end of the site. So I have built that. But the height of the sticky elements influences the space at the beginning of the content.

```
.buttonArea{
   position: sticky;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: white;
   top: calc(100% - 50px); /*minus height of buttonArea*/
}
```

My code you can find here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kqojpcLr/

Of course, I have searched beforehand for a solution. I only found the same problem in another kind (e.q. King Cobra on [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/creating-sliding-effects-using-sticky-positioning/)).

How can I make sure, that the content starts on top? Without the (grey) space between the beginning of the element and the content?

Comment: `margin-bottom: -50px;` to the sticky element?

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work, becauce that shrinks the height of the footer too.

Comment: why you apply it to the footer? apply it to only the header

Comment: I applyed it to .buttonArea and it influenced the footer too,

Comment: `.buttonArea` is not your header ..

Comment: I'm no programmer. Do you mean head{...} If tryed this without succes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quick fix, you could set a negative top margin for the "content" div.

```
.content{ width: 500px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          margin-top:-50px;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But why behaves css that strange?